# plpgsql: strange implicit cast within function

Tags: function, postgresql, casting, plpgsql

I'm using PostgreSQL 8.1.

I'm flummoxed by what's going on with implicit casting in this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION this_is_weird(v_input TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT AS $$
BEGIN
        IF v_input > 113 THEN
                RETURN 'answer1';
        ELSE
                RETURN 'answer2';
        END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The input `'17'` (as a string) gives the return value `'answer1'`.  But if I type

```
SELECT '17' > 113
```

in psql, I get `'f'`.

(I can of course fix the problem by adding an explicit cast, `v_input::integer`.)

Comment: You shouldn't be passing a number as a string in the first place. Why not declare the parameter of type  `integer`?

Comment: Yes, there are obviously ways to get the code to do what I want it to do. I'm asking, rather, about what _appears_ to me to be an inconsistency in implicit casting.

Comment: In 9.2 it is an error: `=> select this_is_weird('17');
ERROR:  operator does not exist: text > integer
LINE 1: SELECT v_input > 113
`

Comment: Re Craig's answer:  I already knew all of that.  What I'm asking about is the _apparent inconsistency_.

Answer (score 2):

In *lexical* comparison, `17` *is* greater than `113`:

```
regress=> SELECT '17' > '113';
?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Don't do text comparisons if you want numeric comparisons.

Because you're comparing a text value with a number the number is being cast to text and compared as text. Your code "works" (ie runs without error) because it's relying on a misfeature in very old PostgreSQL versions where the server would implicitly cast an operand to text where required. This proved to cover up application bugs and made it easy to write silently incorrect code so the implicit casts were removed in 8.3. See [Peter's blog entry](http://petereisentraut.blogspot.com.au/2008/03/readding-implicit-casts-in-postgresql.html) for some information on the topic.

In PostgreSQL 8.3 and above your code would produce an error.

You need to plan an upgrade, it'll save you time and hassle in the long run for all sorts of reasons. The removal of `max_fsm_pages` in favour of auto-tuning it; the visibility map; greatly improved autovacuum; ... there's lots of benefit to upgrading even if you don't need the performance improvements. Read the release notes for each major version (8.2.0, 8.3.0, etc) for upgrade and compatibility advice.